# DataGridView and OnDataSourceChanged

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have custom class, and I want to override OnDataSourceChanged method to read some information about columns. BUt in this methods, columns are not generated yet. I can only access data source columns, but I need to access auto generated DataGridView columns collection. When these columns are generated?

Answer (score 2):

You didn't post your code, but make sure you call the `base.OnDataSourceChanged()` method before trying to access the column collection of the grid control:

```
protected override void OnDataSourceChanged(EventArgs e) {
  base.OnDataSourceChanged(e);  // call this first
  // loop through columns here...
}
```

Comment: Doesn't wotk. But finally I solved my problem with handling OnColumnAdded event.